# R reshape/extract values from array based on pairs of dimensions from another array/dataframe

Tags: r

I have an 3D array of shape [x=16, y=80, t=148]:

```r
a <- array(runif(16*80*148), dim = c(16, 80, 148))
```

I also have a dataframe that consists of n rows of specific x,y pairs (with an ID value):

```r
df <- data.frame(id = seq(1:50),
                 x = floor(runif(50, 1,16)),
                 y = floor(runif(50, 1, 80)))
```

I would like to extract the values from `a` to a new 2D array of shape [n, t] based on the specific x,y pairs provided in `df`.   something like:

```
output <- rbind(a[df$x[1], df$y[1],], 
                a[df$x[2], df$y[2],],
                ...
)
```

So in this example case, the output should be of shape:  50, 148

Is there an efficient way to do this or basically intersect 2 arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt using some matrix indexing, using a much smaller example set of data:

```
a <- array(runif(2*3*3), dim = c(2, 3, 3))
df <- data.frame(id = seq(1:3),
                 x = floor(runif(3, 1, 2)),
                 y = floor(runif(3, 1, 3)))

output <- rbind(
    a[df$x[1], df$y[1],], 
    a[df$x[2], df$y[2],],
    a[df$x[3], df$y[3],]
)
```

Selection all in one go:

```
d3 <- dim(a)[3]
newoutput <- matrix(
    a[cbind(rep(df$x, each=d3), rep(df$y, each=d3), seq_len(d3))],
    nrow=nrow(df), byrow=TRUE
)
```

Matches the expected `output`:

```
identical(output, newoutput)
##[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, this worked.  I had actually come up with a solution using `purrr` as:  `o <- purrr::map2(df$x, df$y, function(i,j) {a[i,j,]})
o2 <- do.call(rbind, o)` but I like your solution better as it doesn't require extra packages